# JavaScript: How Can I Make A Var "Array" Work?

Tags: javascript, arrays, var

Is there a way to name a var using a sort of "Array?" My code is this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < (getHorizontalSquares * getVerticalSquares); i++){
    var Square[i] = document.createElement("div");
    Square[i].style.position = "relative";
    Square[i].style.float = "left";
    Square[i].style.width = "50px";
    Square[i].style.height = "50px";
    Square[i].id = "square" + (i + 1);
    for(var ii = 0; ii < 6; ii++){
        var TestColor = TestColorArray[Math.round(Math.random()*(TestColorArray.length - 1))];
        getTestColor += TestColor;
    }
    Square[i].style.backgroundColor = "#" + getTestColor;
    SquareCont.appendChild(Square[i]);
}
```

I know my code doesn't work, but I want to implement the same idea so I can get a result of this:

```
var Square1...
var Square2...
var Square3...
var Square4...
var Square5...
etc
```

I also tried doing a `"Concentration" var`, but it didn't work. How do I do this so the document doesn't append the same square multiple times?

Comment: You can't do that. Why not just use an `array` and have the indices refer to `i'th` `Square`?

Comment: would using a normal variable not work? like `var square = document.createElement("div");
    square.style.position = "relative";
   square.style.float = "left";`etc...

Comment: You can do that by adding properties to an OBJECT, but not an array... You can just add the new divs you make to an array and it is essentially what you are after. `var square = {};` then in your for loop: `square['Square'+i] = 'something';` Will get you an object (square), where you have square.Square1, square.Square2, etc etc, And you can loop through an objects properties, like you can an array.

Comment: @JohanP I thought about that, but I thought I could do a shortcut.

Comment: @AndrewLohr When I tried that, the other div's background color wouldn't change.

Comment: It's not possible. However, you could sort of do this using an `Object` like `var Squares = { Square1: ..., Square2: ... }` and reference using `Squares['Square1']` or `Squares['Square' + 1]`. In that case, however, you may as well just use an array as opposed to using such a convoluted route.

Comment: @AndrewLohr yep, and it turns out, this wasn't an issue. It was the hexadecimal value that wasn't being reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var Square = {};
var SquareCont = document.createElement('div');
var getHorizontalSquares = 10;
var getVerticalSquares = 10;
var TestColorArray = ['a','b','c','f','e','0','1','2','3','3','4','5'];
var getTestColor = '';
for(var i = 0; i < (getHorizontalSquares * getVerticalSquares); i++){
    Square['Square'+i] = document.createElement("div");
    Square['Square'+i].style.position = "relative";
    Square['Square'+i].style.float = "left";
    Square['Square'+i].style.width = "50px";
    Square['Square'+i].style.height = "50px";
    Square['Square'+i].id = "square" + (i + 1);
    for(var ii = 0; ii < 6; ii++){
        var TestColor = TestColorArray[Math.round(Math.random()*(TestColorArray.length - 1))];
        getTestColor += TestColor;
    }
    Square['Square'+i].style.backgroundColor = "#" + getTestColor;
    SquareCont.appendChild(Square['Square'+i]);
    getTestColor = '';
    
}
console.log(Square);
```

This example does what you want using an object instead of an array, but meets your desire to dynamically create accessible Square1, Square2, etc... They are all contained in Square. In the console with this snippet, you will see that 100 squares are created and added to the Square object. They will be accessible by Square.SquareX (where X is some number), or Square['SquareX'], or Square['Square'+X] where X is some number again.

Comment: you fixed the problem I had. It was for a completely different reason: The hexadecimal code wasn't being reset. I figured out the problem, too. It was that I didn't have this line: `getTestColor = '';`

Comment: Haha, glad you got it!

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration syntax is not valid. But, I think the larger point you are trying to get to is to be able to populate an array with dynamically created elements and that you can do:

```js
var squares = [];  // Array must exist before you can populate it

var testColorArray = ["green", "yellow", "blue", "orange", "silver"];
var getTestColor = null;

function makeSquares(count){

  for(var i = 0; i < count; i++){
    // Just create the element and configure it. No need to worry about the array yet
    var element = document.createElement("div");
    element.style.float = "left";
    element.style.width = "75px";
    element.style.height = "75px";
    element.id = "square" + (i + 1);
    element.style.backgroundColor = testColorArray[Math.floor(Math.random()* testColorArray.length)];
    element.textContent = element.id;
    squareCont.appendChild(element);
    
    // Now, add the element to the arrray
    squares.push(element);
  }
  
  // Test:
  console.log(squares);
}

makeSquares(10);
```

```html
<div id="squareCont"></div>
```